beforeSoftRemove hook not updating database entry using Nest.js and TypeORM
I want to implement a solution in Nest.js and TypeORM application that every record that is getting created should have createdById, updatedById and deletedById against their actions. Let me share the code snippets and explain better:
Entity File
@Entity('todo-list')
export class TodoList {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({
    type: 'varchar',
    length: 255,
    nullable: false,
  })
  name: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true, default: null })
  createdById: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, { nullable: true })
  createdBy: User;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true, default: null })
  updatedById: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, { nullable: true })
  updatedBy: User;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', nullable: true, default: null })
  deletedById: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, { nullable: true })
  deletedBy: User;
}

Now I have a subscriber like this:
export class GlobalSubscriber implements EntitySubscriberInterface {
  beforeInsert(event: InsertEvent<any>): void {
    if (!event.entity.createdById) {
      event.entity.createdById = 'userId';
    }
  }

  beforeUpdate(event: UpdateEvent<any>): void {
    if (!event.entity.updatedById) {
      event.entity.updatedById = 'userId';
    }
  }

  beforeSoftRemove(event: RemoveEvent<any>): void {
    if (!event.entity.deletedById) {
      event.entity.deletedById = 'userId';
    }
  }
}


beforeInsert and beforeUpdate is working as expected. However, beforeSoftRemove is getting triggered but it is not updating the column in database. I have tried to catch the soft remove event in beforeUpdate method as well. But nothing works.
Just for your knowledge, here is the code how I am soft removing a record:
await this.todoRepository.softRemove(todoObject);

I want to use subscriber so that I don't have to add this functionality to each and every entity. Could you suggest a possible solution for this approach?

The softRemove method from the Repository API is not a simple update operation, what it will do is set a timestamp in the deletedAt field in your TodoList entity automatically (which you don't have, you should add it), that's why it's not performing the update you are expecting. The actual event.entity.deletedById property is being set correctly in your subscriber method, if you log it afterwards you'll see that it's being set, but softRemove will just update the deletedAt value. You need to create your own custom repository or do it separately.
Create a custom repository:
// todoList.repository.ts 

export interface TodoListRepository extends Repository<TodoList> {
  this: Repository<TodoList>;
  softRemove(): Promise<TodoList>;
}

export const customTodoListRepository: Pick<ToDoListRepository, any> = {
  softRemove(this: Repository<TodoList>, todoObject) {
    await this.softRemove(todoObject);
    todoObject.deletedById = 'userId';
    return this.save(todoObject)
  },
};

// todoList.service.ts
// inject the custom repository in your service
...
...
constructor(
    @InjectRepository(TodoList) private readonly todoListRepository: TodoListRepository,
  ) {}

Do it separately (easiest way):
await this.todoRepository.softRemove(todoObject);
todoObject.deletedById = 'userId';
return this.todoRepository.save(todoObject)

A similar question that might help your purposes:
SoftDelete: Can't set flag deletedBy, deletedAt
